# Filter web notifications by client-side

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, firebase-notifications

When I send a notification to some **topic** like...

```
const message = {
  data: { cost: 49 },
  topic: 'apple'
}
admin.messaging().send(message)
```

Question is about **preventing/filtering notifications** if user set something like **>= 50** ? (Firestore/localStorage?)

How can I do that?

As I can think it should be filtered with **messaging-sw.js** but how and it's possible?

Or any better idea or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1: [When your app is in the foreground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_foreground)

Case 2: [When your app is in background](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_background)

- Save the user's data in **[IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)**, since users can access IndexedDB data in the service worker
- You have to customize the function **setBackgroundMessageHandler** in the **firebase-messaging-sw.js** file as **[this guideline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#setting_notification_options_in_the_service_worker)** to handle the user's options
- Note: If you set notification fields in your message payload, your setBackgroundMessageHandler callback is not called, and instead the SDK displays a notification based on your payload.

Anyway, using a filter on the client-side is not a good approach, it should be done in server-side

Comment: Thanks I got this when I researched also (but I did not tested yet), Do you confirm it should work? so I will accept this answer.